# How can i repeat same activity after user has chosen right option?

Tags: android-activity, restart

```
   ImageView Iv2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            textId++;
            String imgId = "full_" + textId;
            int Ivid = getResources().getIdentifier(imgId, "drawable", getPackageName());  
            Iv2.setImageResource(Ivid);
            Iv2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    clapping =  MediaPlayer.create(textBasedquiz.this, R.raw.applause);
                    clapping.start();
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**Basically im trying to build an quiz for kids and in this im selecting images randomly i want to restart same code after user has touch on right image so he/she can get another question , but activity must start after sound has been played Please Guys help me i really need your valued comments **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setResult and go to activity from where you have called your this activity. Pass the value along and based on result of value received, call the saem activity passing new value that you just got from the same activity.

```
  static int RESULT_OK = 100;
  STATIC INT RESULT_CANCEL = 110;

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      switch(resultCode) {
          case RESULT_OK:
               // Get flags/values from intent Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION

               // Create new activity setting the intent to call
               // and pass the values      
               startActivity(intent);    
               break;
      }
  }
```

I think this will be more straight forward rather than calling same Activity from itself only.

Comment: If u can help me by elaborating REsult_ok REsult_cancel ?